# Removing rows where the number of interest is below cut-off (Perl)

Tags: perl

I have files with several columns that contain text in the following format “number/number:zero,number_of_interest”. Example: “1/1:0,13”.

I need to remove rows if the number of interest is less than 20 in any of the columns. 
I prefer to use egrep and not to read in the file but not sure how to evaluate the number of interest in each column in a single statement.

I’m also removing rows that contain SVLEN=-1 or SVLEN=-2 and it seems to be working well with egrep:

```
$cmd2 = `egrep -v 'SVLEN=-1;|SVLEN=-2;' $my_vcf > $my_new_vcf`; print $cmd1;
```

I've tried the following but it did not work:

```
my $cmd2 = `egrep -v 'SVLEN=-1;|SVLEN=-2;|(\,(\d+) < 20)' $my_vcf > $my_new_vcf`; print $cmd2;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show some complete input lines. Do they contain multiple columns as in `"1/1:0,13","1/1:0,14","1/1:0,30"`? How are these columns separated? By comma `,`? Are they surrounded by quotes `"`? And why do you want to use `egrep` from a Perl script? Perl will be much better in this case than `egrep`.

Comment: Yes, multiple columns separated by tab but there is multi-line header as well. The number of columns may be different in each file. There are no quotes in the file. the lines look like this 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,10 when i print on command line. Other suggestions are welcome. thank you.

Comment: complete input line: chr7    55242417        .       ACTCTGGATCCCAGAAGGTGAGAAAGTTAAAATTCCCGTCGCTATCAAGGAATTAAGAGAAGC AACTCTGGATCCCAGAAGGTGAGAAAGTTAAAATTCCCGT                                                                                                     CGCTATCAA       .       PASS    END=55242479;HOMLEN=0;SVLEN=-62;SVTYPE=RPL;NTLEN=48     GT:AD   0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,0 0/0:0,10                                                                                                     /0:0,0

Comment: is it possible to do this in one line with Perl? Or you have to open each file read in line by line and split by tab? thanks

Comment: Of course. The line will be a bit long and probably not easy to read, though. But why this restriction? You already have a Perl script! Why don't you stick with that?

Comment: i don't understand how it is possible to do this without opening and reading the file line by line.  Could you please demonstrate.

Comment: *"I prefer to use egrep and not to read in the file"* Do you realise that `egrep` also has to "read the file"? There is no way to filter data without reading it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`egrep` is the wrong tool for this purpose as it can't do math within its regular expression.
Because you already have a Perl script you are better off using Perl commands to achieve your goal.

Unfortunately you have to open and read the file line by line to do so, but that is exactly what `egrep` does. How else could it judge the lines?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util;

sub filter_lines
{
    my $in_filename  = shift;
    my $out_filename = shift;
    open( my $fhin,  '<', $in_filename )  or die "cannot open $in_filename: $!\n";
    open( my $fhout, '>', $out_filename ) or die "cannot open $out_filename: $!\n";
    while ( my $line = <$fhin> ) {

        next if ( $line =~ /SVLEN=-1;|SVLEN=-2;/ );
        if ( my @numbers_of_interest = ( $line =~ m/\d+\/\d+:0,(\d+)/g ) ) {
            next unless List::Util::min(@numbers_of_interest) < 20;
        }

        print $fhout $line;

    }
    close($fhin);
    close($fhout);
}

filter_lines( $my_vcf, $my_new_vcf );
```

Because I have no exact input line the pattern for the `@numbers_of_interest` might be a bit inaccurate and need improvement. There's also much room for optimization in case this code turns out to be slow.

Comment: I'm not able to use List::Util::min.

Comment: @user3781528: Why can't you use `List::Util::min`? The line `use List::Utils;` should be `use List::Util ();`—does that solve your problem?

Comment: i was able to use use List::Util qw( min max );